# how to fix variable not assigned error in scanner in java

Tags: java

taking input from user but while printing output it shows null and 0 as output

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class College
{
    int id,rollno;
    String name;
    void input()
    {
        Scanner my = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter id");
        int id =my.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter name");
        String name = my.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter roll no");
        int rollno = my.nextInt();
    }
       void display()
    {
    System.out.println(" id :"+id);
    System.out.println(" name : "+name);
    System.out.println("rollno :"+rollno);

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       College sc = new College();`enter code here`
        sc.input();
        sc.display();
    }
}



enter id
1
enter name
enter roll no
34
 id :0
 name : null
rollno :0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

not getting output as input entered

Answer (score 1):

Set the class fields instead of defining new local variables with the same names.

```
void input()
{
    Scanner my = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter id");
    int id =my.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter name");
    String name = my.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter roll no");
    int rollno = my.nextInt();
}
```

should be

```
void input()
{
    Scanner my = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter id");
    this.id = my.nextInt();
    my.nextLine(); // <-- consume trailing newline.
    System.out.println("enter name");
    this.name = my.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter roll no");
    this.rollno = my.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class College
{
    private int id, rollno;
    private String name;

    void input() {
        Scanner my = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter id");
        id = my.nextInt();   
        my.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter name");
        name = my.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter roll no");
        rollno = my.nextInt();
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println("id: " + id);
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        System.out.println("rollno: " + rollno);   
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        College sc = new College();
        sc.input();
        sc.display();
    }
}
```

Note that:

`id = my.nextInt()`

consumes only the integer, but it skips the newline \n. To get around this problem, you may need to add an additional

```
input.nextLine()
```

after you read the int, which can consume the \n.

The output is:

```
enter id
2471
enter name
John
enter roll no
85
id: 2471
name: John
rollno: 85
```